# communicating Dialog with in a dialog in mfc

Tags: mfc

how to communicate or send messages from dialog1 to dialog2(sub dialog of dialog1) in MFC

Answer (score 2):

1) `#define  MYMSG   WM_USER + 3`

2) define and implement disp. function in your dialog `LRESULT OnMyMsg(WPARAM w, LPARAM l);`

3) Add code to your message map `ON_MESSAGE(MYMSG,OnMyMsg)`

4) Send message `myDlgPtr->SendMessage(MYMSG,0,0);`

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644950(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)